# Baking time and temperature difference

Tags: baking, thanksgiving

I am baking a canned sweet potato casserole for Thanksgiving. The recipe calls for the dish to be baked at 400 degrees for 25 minutes. Problem is my other sides call for an oven temperature to be 350 degrees for 30 minutes.  Is it possible to put the sweet potatoes in at 350 degrees and just bake a little longer?

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. Bake the casserole for a while longer at 350, just crank up the heat (to 500 even) at the end to get the browning on the top after you remove the other stuff. Casseroles are very forgiving by nature.